# How to send Map<Long,Photo> using Postman?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, postman

I have a DTO Photo object

```
public class Photo {
     private final MultipartFile photo;
}
```

I am sending a map to the controller

```
@RequestBody Map<Long, Photo> map;
```

But I do not know how to set the value of Long and how to set the file. How do you do it with the help of the Postman tool?

Comment: It is impossible to do with postmap

Comment: Can this be done with some other tool?

Comment: I don't know any existing tools which allow to do it. You can write your own class to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Postman deals with Http protocol. So the messages you send by Postman must be in some standard format, which, in your case, might be application/json. If this is the case, you must serialize your programming objects into JSON format, and send it by Postman. Map is typically serialized as JSON dictionary. So `Map<Long, Photo>` would be something like `{123: #Photo1#, 234: #Photo2#}`. Objects are typically viewed as collections of key/value pairs, which are also serialized as JSON dictionary. So, the final format of JSON message would be something like `{123: {"photo": #MultipartFile1#}, 234: {"photo": #MultipartFile1#"}}`. And you must determine further what `#MultipartFile1#` is serialized.

Comment: But I do not know how to add this file to the body https://zapodaj.net/a88ac80f64561.png.html